# How to randomly rotate many linked array objects along their individual origins

Tags: modifiers, random

I have 30x50 matrix (2 arrrays) of roughly 1500 cubes that I want to each randomly rotate around their individual origins to achieve similar effect:

[image]

Thus far have most success with 2 array modifiers first applied, then separated by loose parts and finally set their all Origins to Geometry:

[image]

Ideally will be to have them all linked (which is not a case in method above).
I played a while with geometry nodes and came up with such node tree:
[image]

It would be ideal, but obvious problem is that it has lacks randomness in vertical orientation.

Has anybody any idea how to make it work like in first or second picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are making your life yourself to difficult, just choose the easy way...

[image]

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome